# How to get content of a non-specific DIV-Element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've a problem and I hope that it's possible to explain.

I have a lot of short texts which come from a mysql-DB.

```
while ($foo = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
  $text = $foo -> column_text_db;
  echo '<div class="atextdiv">' . $text . '</div>';
  }
```

now i want to add an onclik-Event-Handler to the "atextdiv"-Container(s) who takes the content and put it on an input-field:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="clickcontent" />
</form>
```

My problem: Each page has a different number of records in database. The final HTML-Code (after parsing the PHP-Code) could be:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div class="atextdiv">Papa was a rolling stone</div>
 <div class="atextdiv">Oh my god! They killed Kenny</div>
 <div class="atextdiv">Foo Bar</div>
 <!-- more content -->
 </div>
 <form>
 <input type="text" id="clickcontent" />
 </form>
```

So, how can I get the content of each "atextdiv"-Container after click on it?

Answer (score 3):

Just like:

```
$(".atextdiv").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Use a combination of `this` and the `.text` method inside the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind click event on `'.atextdiv'` and in event fetch its value using [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.atextdiv', funnction(){
    $("#clickcontent").val($(this).text())
})
```

Comment: Ideally you should bind to a closer common ancestor than `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the innerHTML of the item that the click event is occurring on:

```
$('.atextdiv').click(function(e){
    alert(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9VE6A/8/